# Git react folder in Gitlab

Tags: reactjs, git, gitlab

I'm going to make a git to my project include spring and react, as shown below:

[image: the content in my project folder]

after I create a local repo and just push this into gitlab as it told me: btw before I git push I have to write "git pull --rebase origin main", otherwise I can't push my repo to gitlab. But I think that is maybe not the reason.
[image: the process I have made to push the local repo to gitlab]

And afterwards it has problem with the react folder in gitlab, and there is no problem with the spring folder, as shown below: I can't open the react folder in gitlab.

[image: how it looks like in the gitlab]

So my question was: why only the react folder has this problem but spring not? and how can I fix it? When I open the react folder by vs code, the version control tool also doesn't work when I made some changes.

Very thankful for answering!

Comment: I can't see a problem. You've added `delivery-react` as a submodule - it's behaving as it should in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why only the react folder has this problem but spring not?

Because `delivery-react` is probably a nested Git repository (meaning there is a `delivery-react/.git)`, unless you have a `.gitmodules` file in your main repository.

If you want to add `delivery-react` as a regular folder:

```bash
git rm --cached delivery-react  # no trailing /
git commit -m "Remove nested folder"
git add delivery-react
git commit -m "Add deliver-react"
git push
```

Comment: I have tried but it shows: <pre>$ git rm delivery-react
error: the following file has local modifications:
    delivery-react
(use --cached to keep the file, or -f to force removal)</pre>

Comment: Yes you can use the --cached option

Comment: Ye, I have tried again, but it seems it still has the same problem, I can't push the new changes in vs code. Or did I wrong in somewhere else? If I want to use spring as backend and react as frontend, shall I put this two project in the same folder or shall I create a react project in spring folder?

Comment: Did you add and commit? What is the error message? Did you try the push from command line?

Comment: There is no error message, but I can't push or pull in react folder, I choose to set git submodule to work on react and spring project respectiveky

Comment: @Esoteriker OK then, a git submodule would be listed by its tree sha1, as expected.